# how to use vector<Point2f> in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use this code([source](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)) to find fundamental matrix in opencv.

```
int point_count = 100;
    vector<Point2f> points1(point_count);
    vector<Point2f> points2(point_count);

    // initialize the points here ... */
    for( int i = 0; i < point_count; i++ )
    {
        points1[i] = ...;
        points2[i] = ...;
    }

    Mat fundamental_matrix =
     findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99);
```

but I don't know how to initialise points1, points2 in for loop.
I have tried using:

```
points1[i] = 10.0;
points1[i] = (10.0, 20.0);
points1[i] = {10.0, 20.0};
```

but getting error like this

```
no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘cv::Point_<float>’ and ‘double’)
```

in all of them.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `cv::Point_`?

Comment: @kevin i have edited the question please take a look

Comment: @RahulKSingh Your edit invalidated all the previous answers, you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Galik Not anymore, i rolled back the qwuestion, because it was too big a change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should be initialized like the following:

```
points[i] = Point2f(0.3f, 0.f);
```

Check OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=point2f).

Comment: I tried your solution and not getting any errors in points[i] = Point2f(0.3f, 0.f); but getting this error in  Mat fundamental_matrix;, undefined reference to `cv::findFundamentalMat(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, int, double, double, cv::_OutputArray const&)'

Comment: This is a linking error, you're not linking with the implementation of the function `cv::findFundamentalMat`.

Comment: As suggested by Ben, it's better to ask a new question about the new issue.

Comment: Code from the documentation:
 `Point_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y);
 typedef Point_<float> Point2f;`. Why he needs to invoke the constructor *explicitly* when there is no `explicit` keyword with the constructor?